# Fourier transformation of $\cos^2(\pi t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need to fouriertransform the function

> $$f(t) = \cos^2(\pi t)$$

First question is if there is some kind of theorem to solve it in a very easy way but I don't know what will happen to the square in the transformation.

Or second thought is to write it as F$\{\cos(\pi t)\}$$\times$ F$\{\cos(\pi t)\}$ and solve this.

Do you have any tips for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to do the convolution?

Comment: now i am kind of confused do i have to do the convolution for the transformed cosinus functions or the normal ones and transform afterwards?